ggplot: Extending axis ticks and putting boxes around axis items
This visualization shows the distribution of responses and the prompt text for a collection of Likert (agree/disagree) items.  I'd like to make it a little easier for readers to connect the prompt text to the corresponding bar, by putting a box around each prompt and extending the axis tick mark to the appropriate box.  

It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a short, representative sample of your data. Please [edit] your question and paste the output of the dput(data) command (preferred) or in tab delimited form. This will help users here answer your question. See this for more: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

Seems like you could do this with geom_label instead of using the axis text itself. Happy to help supply code if the question's made reproducible, per the prior comment.

I imagine this plot would also be improved by turning off scale expansion (e.g. + coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)).

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use ggtext::element_markdown which allows to draw a box around the axis text. Note however, that this requires to use a <br> tag to add line breaks instead of \n.
Using some fake example data:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:12,
  y = sapply(1:12, \(x) lorem::ipsum_words(12))
)

p <- ggplot(dat) +
  geom_col(
    aes(x, y)
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = \(x) label_wrap_gen()(x) |> gsub("\\n", "<br>", x = _),
    guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(
      box.color = "black",
      linetype = 1,
      padding = unit(2, "pt"),
      linewidth = .25
    )
  )

For the axis ticks you can use a vector to get ticks of different lengths as suggested by @Axeman
p +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.length.y = rel(c(3, 50))
  )


or as a second option use e.g. annotate to fake the axis ticks using a geom_segment which however requires some fiddling to get the lengths right:
p +
  annotate(
    "segment",
    x = 0, xend = -5,
    y = seq(2, 12, 2),
    yend = seq(2, 12, 2),
    linewidth = .5
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(
    clip = "off", xlim = c(0, NA), expand = FALSE
  )



This is also what I would do to get the boxes (+1). You can't connect them with the ticks though, e.g. axis.ticks.length.y = rel(c(3, 50)) will just move the boxes over to the left.

Thx @Axeman. Yes. Using axis.ticks.length.y was also my first option for the axis ticks. Added you4r suggestion and as a second option an approach using annotate.
